# Android NDK and bluetooth

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-bluetooth

I'm new in android ndk.
So, is it possible to work with bluetooth using android NDK (same as in SDK or similar)  on not rooted devices.
If possible, give me direction where to find more info about that.
Thanks alot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no direct access to Bluetooth APIs from the NDK.
The list of available NDK APIs is inside `docs/STABLE-APIS.html` from the NDK archive.

But that doesn't mean that you shouldn't use Bluetooth from the NDK.
You can directly call Java Android APIs and manipulate Java objects from C/C++ using JNI.

JNI calls are quite tedious to do, so in order to minimize these I would recommend you to write all the Bluetooth-related code you need in Java, as a "Helper" class, and use JNI to call this helper from your C/C++ code.